# XSL find nodes that have the key as sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have this (quite odd) XML, with 7 children from 4 families. 
There are 5 boys that have 6 apples and 9 oranges and 2 girls that have 3 apples and 3 oranges.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fruits.xsl"?>
<report>
    <family>
        <gender>
            <boyorgirl>Boy</boyorgirl>
                <person>
                    <apples>1</apples>
                    <oranges>1</oranges>
                    <id>1</id>
                </person>
        </gender>
        <gender>
            <boyorgirl>Girl</boyorgirl>
                <person>
                    <apples>2</apples>
                    <oranges>0</oranges>
                    <id>2</id>
                </person>
        </gender>
        <gender>
            <boyorgirl>Boy</boyorgirl>
                <person>
                    <apples>1</apples>
                    <oranges>4</oranges>
                    <id>3</id>
                </person>
        </gender>
    </family>
    <family>
        <gender>
            <boyorgirl>Girl</boyorgirl>
                <person>
                    <apples>1</apples>
                    <oranges>3</oranges>
                    <id>4</id>
                </person>
        </gender>
    </family>
    <family>
        <gender>
            <boyorgirl>Boy</boyorgirl>
                <person>
                    <apples>1</apples>
                    <oranges>0</oranges>
                    <id>5</id>
                </person>
        </gender>
    </family>
    <family>
        <gender>
            <boyorgirl>Boy</boyorgirl>
                <person>
                    <apples>2</apples>
                    <oranges>2</oranges>
                    <id>6</id>
                </person>
                <person>
                    <apples>1</apples>
                    <oranges>2</oranges>
                    <id>7</id>
                </person>
        </gender>
    </family>
</report>
```

I want to count how many persons there are for each gender, and how many apples and oranges they have together. 
I don't want to hardcode on gender in those modern days, in case someone should claim they have another gender than boy or girl. Expected output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<fruitcounting xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <fruitline>
        <boyorgirl>Boy</boyorgirl>
        <numberOfPersons>5</numberOfPersons>
        <apples>6</apples>
        <oranges>9</oranges>
    </fruitline>
    <fruitline>
        <boyorgirl>Girl</boyorgirl>
        <numberOfPersons>2</numberOfPersons>
        <apples>3</apples>
        <oranges>3</oranges>
    </fruitline>
</fruitcounting>
```

I have the beginning of a stylesheet, but it just counts members and fruits in the first family - how can I change it so it finds all boys/girls, irrespective of family? Or, I think I could formulate it as all nodes that have the key as preceding sibling.

I can only use XSL 1.0 without extensions

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="fruits" match="gender" use="boyorgirl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fruitcounting>

        <xsl:for-each select="//gender[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('fruits', boyorgirl)[1])]">

            <fruitline>
                <boyorgirl><xsl:value-of select="boyorgirl"/></boyorgirl>
                <numberOfPersons><xsl:value-of select="count(../gender/person/id)"/></numberOfPersons>
                <apples><xsl:value-of select="sum(../gender/person/apples)"/></apples>
                <oranges><xsl:value-of select="sum(../gender/person/oranges)"/></oranges>

            </fruitline>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </fruitcounting>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `<numberOfPersons><xsl:value-of select="count(../gender/person/id)"/></numberOfPersons>` with `<numberOfPersons><xsl:value-of select="count(key('fruits', boyorgirl)/person)"/></numberOfPersons>` and use the `key` function the same way to idenfity your groups, e.g. `<apples><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('fruits', boyorgirl)/person/apples)"/></apples>` in the other computations.

So the complete code becomes

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="fruits" match="gender" use="boyorgirl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fruitcounting>

        <xsl:for-each select="//gender[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('fruits', boyorgirl)[1])]">

            <fruitline>
                <boyorgirl><xsl:value-of select="boyorgirl"/></boyorgirl>
                <numberOfPersons><xsl:value-of select="count(key('fruits', boyorgirl)/person)"/></numberOfPersons>
                <apples><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('fruits', boyorgirl)/person/apples)"/></apples>
                <oranges><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('fruits', boyorgirl)/person/oranges)"/></oranges>

            </fruitline>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </fruitcounting>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

online at http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsb.